# Conditional Post thumbnail with slider

Tags: wordpress

I want to use this, if their is a slider , then show this. if their is no slider , then it will show a image. My code is like this. but their only showing the image though their is a slider image. if I remove the image part with the condition , then the slider is showing. what is the problem in my code. will anyone please answer ?

```
    <div class="slideshow">
        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail('slider-image')) : ?>
        <div data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide" id="carousel-example-generic">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <?php
                global $post;
                $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'post_type'=> 'slider-items');
                $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                $count = 0;
                foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="<?php echo $count++;?>"></li>
                <?php endforeach; 
                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
            <?php
                global $post;
                $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'post_type'=> 'slider-items');
                $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
                    <div class="item">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('slider-image'); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; 
                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php else :?>
            <div class="fixed_slider">
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/slider-fixed.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div>
```

Comment: `has_post_thumbnail()` accepts a post ID as a parameter, not a string. `has_post_thumbnail('slider-image')` will always return false. Please explain more about that slider-image thing. What is this? Where is this being configure and how?

Comment: i added custom post to use this slider. when this theme first installed , then there is no any slider. so this page is empty. now from the fist time before added slider , i wanna use a image in the slider area. then when i add slider image from dashboard, then this image will not show. then only the slider will show. thats i want. hope, i have made u understand.

Comment: what should i change/add here  if i use this condition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to keep getting the same posts over and over again.

To check if there is posts in slider-items post type or not, you first get the posts outside the if statement. Then, check if there is any posts or not. If there is, do the slider else, fixed image.

Try something like this.

```
<div class="slideshow">
  <?php
  $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'post_type'=> 'slider-items');
  $sliderposts = get_posts( $args );
  if ( count($sliderposts) > 0) : ?>
  <div data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide" id="carousel-example-generic">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <?php
      $count = 0;
      foreach( $sliderposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="<?php echo $count++;?>"></li>
      <?php endforeach; 
      wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php
      foreach( $sliderposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <div class="item">
          <?php the_post_thumbnail('slider-image'); ?>
        </div>
      <?php endforeach; 
      wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php else :?>
    <div class="fixed_slider">
      <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/slider-fixed.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much. there was few problems in my code.